# Wordpress 500 internal server error after changing permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I got 500 internal server error after changing wordpress permalinks. It gives me the same error for all the options except the plain one.

[image]

The error is only on the post pages. Many people say that wordpress is not allowed to edit .htaccess file. However, I have a plugin which edited my .htaccess file successfully.

Two more things that might be important I use proxy to run the blog and here is what inside .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you checked their [manual](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-error-after-changing-permalinks) at all, before doing changes to `.htaccess`?

Comment: Have a look in your error log.

Comment: I didn't change .htaccess file. Moreover, this is not my case I want both the blog is up and the custom permalink is set.

Comment: here is the error message in the log.
`[Fri Jul 08 04:48:24.237062 2016] [core:error] [pid 2430] [client 46.101.144.77:36922] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://6-cylinder.com/news/`

Answer (score 1):

Rename your htaccess  file and then set permalinks plain and save setting it will create new htaccess file , then set post name permalink again and save the setting

hope this will work for you

Comment: Yes it created a new .httaccess file. but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Internal server errors (error 500) are often caused by plugin or theme function conflicts, so  try deactivating all plugins. If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.If that does not resolve the issue, try switching to the Twenty Fourteen theme to rule-out a theme-specific issue.